# How does Android Studio import Gradle projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've read lots of "how-to" guides to importing libraries into Android Studio (now the only *supported* Android SDK, hmmpf) yet none of them explain what's actually going on during an import.

**I can see projects that have Gradle build files everywhere and some that have none, why is this?**

Half the stuff I get on Git-hub to play around with takes me more time to successfully import than the time it's saved me by using. My question is, what is required to successfully import and use your average library (project, not JAR or AAR) in Android Studio without having to refactor half the stuff?

Eclipse would allow me to use one single project (folder structure, not jar) as an "external" library and I needn't define what needs compiling where and when.
Android Studio keeps making copies of the project library inside my project folder then proceeds to complain about a whole host of things whilst it pollutes my project space with incorrectly named folders and packages (See screenshots)

[image: incomplete import]

> Here's and incomplete import where I only imported the "core" folder
>   because I don't need this other blokes extra stuff - but it's missing
>   some definitions.

[image]

Here's a complete import of the whole folder (as you can see, samples
and all) but it's polluted my project folder and I don't need the
majority of it, and there's all these individual references now to
dependencies and things I don't think I should need.

> How do I properly import a whole library with it's dependencies
>   without it polluting my current project?

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**
Ok here's what I have in one case of a library for an example.

> The root folder of the zipped library - lots of garbage I don't need
>   [image]

What do I need to do to use this library? If I import the whole folder using Android Studio's "Import module" feature, it just makes a mess.
If I import just the "Core" folder it semi-works, but lacks *some* dependencies.

1. Why are there 3 individual gradle.build files?
2. Why are the required components in separate folders?
3. Should I just manually copy an arbitrary number of folders to my *new* "Libraries" folder under the root of my project?

**Importing via File->Import Module**
[image]

So the "sample" *"module"* (library..) requires the "layout" and "core" modules, that makes sense. **But why if they're required aren't they all in the one module, using the same gradle.build file?**

Now I've done that, I get this "Error:(23, 0) Could not read script 'C:\Users\me\AndroidstudioProjects\MyApp\gradle\scripts\gradle-mvn-push.gradle' as it does not exist."
It does exist at C:\Users\me\place_the_module_was_imported_from\gradle\scripts\ though, but

> why if it's needed, was it not copied? Is this just bad Gradle...'ing?

**Again, thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found what seems to be the closest answer to this.

### 10 Gradle Basics

The addition of Gradle is going to be your largest hurdle during your transition over to Android Studio. Here are the basics of what you need to know:

- Your Android Studio project will have a settings.gradle for the whole project
- The settings.gradle file includes references to all modules which are included in the project and is generally updated automatically when you import or create a new module
- Each Android Studio module will have its own build.gradle file
- If one module depends upon another module, you will need to add that dependency in the build.gradle under the dependencies section
- If your Module requries a jar file, it must be listed in that Module's build.gradle file
  You may add remote dependencies to your project by listing them in a module's build.gradle file
  From time to time, you will need to manually edit these gradle files Read more about Gradle over here.

Problem is that dependencies show up as modules in the UI so I now have a polluted workspace full of single-use libraries.

Comment: Also at the beginning of the gradle.build file for each "module" you're using, you must indicated that it is a library and not an application with:
**apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library via `gradle.build` and the necessary dependencies will be neatly added to your project without "polluting" your project. An example is the `Facebook SDK`

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
}
```

As you can see from the image, the only place to know the external libraries am using is in the `libraries` folder of my project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you haven't explained how, as it stands though I'm more aware of what gradle's doing now, I just think Android Studio is confusing because of it's various (Android, Project, Packages) views and how it decides to display things.

How you created this libraries folder and the layout of it would be good to know though, why are there xml files in the root of that folder? Wouldn't they be in their own respective folders?

Answer (score 0):

Add .jar file in your project

1 - Create libs folder under the app folder.
2 - copy your .jar file 
3 - paste in app->libs folder
4 - after Click on File menu and select Project Structer option and open it
5 - Open one window in left side Modules under App folder select that folder
6 - In your window Top display 5 Option menu in select Dependencies option
7 - Then Right side display "+" "-" Sign click on "+" sign
8 - then open small dialog and choice "File dependencies" option 
9 - then open another dialog here navigate .jar file in your libs folder and    select
10 - click on Ok button and Apply And ok

---

add module project

1 - Click on File menu and select Import Module option
2 - then open one window here navigate your module and  Finish
3 - Click on File menu and select Project Structer option and open it
4 - Open one window in left side Modules under App folder select that folder
5 - In your window Top display 5 Option menu in select Dependencies option
6 - Then Right side display "+" "-" Sign click on "+" sign
5 - then open small dialog and choice "Module dependencies" option 
6 - then open another dialog here Module and select
7 - click on Ok button and Apply And ok

Comment: No Jar available. This is for a "project" folder or "module" as Android Studio calls it. Thanks though

Comment: same process you can Add project or module

Comment: give screen short but not enough reputation so sorry